# Force browser update if browser not latest version

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

How can I force user to update browser before display website content if browser not latest version by JavaScript specially google chrome users

Comment: Even google chrome can't force users to update. I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: You **cannot** force it and you **should not** be doing this, even if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can only hide the website depending of your condition.
You can't force any download, fortunately.

Except if the user had already download any browser pluggin of your.

Comment: how can I check if browser is uptodate or no ? by js

Comment: In one word: Impossible. In reality: the huge task is only in the field of browsers's developers.